# Docker using wrong socket path after uninstalling docker desktop

Tags: docker

Using KDE Neon

I installed docker desktop using these instructions:
https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/ubuntu/

After having problems with it, I uninstalled using

```bash
$ sudo apt remove docker-desktop
$ rm -r $HOME/.docker/desktop
$ sudo rm /usr/local/bin/com.docker.cli
$ sudo apt purge docker-desktop
```

Then I installed docker with these instructions:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#set-up-the-repository

Docker runs fine when using sudo, but without it's using the wrong socket path.

```
machi@machi-kde-surface:~$ docker run hello-world
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/machi/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.
machi@machi-kde-surface:~$
```

I've checked `/etc/init/docker.conf` but but it seems fine. Where is it getting this old desktop path from?

Comment: sudo docker run... would work? did you run the next steps for permissions?

Comment: Yeah, permissions were all good. /home/<user>/.docker is where some desktop config files were hiding

Comment: if docker service hasn't started you'd get that message. Have you tried "sudo service docker start"

Comment: you shouldn't have to change your .docker file. if docker isn't running you'd get that message as well.

Answer (score 1):

Removed `/home/<user>/.docker`, reinstalled docker, and now it works.